# How do I make voice responses control flow in a Twilio phone call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have Twilio working with keypad responses. Now I want to do the same with calls where the responses are recorded and transcribed. For keypad I have

```
def digits
  twiml_response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Gather numDigits: '1', timeout: 1, action: 
             communications_menu_path(@question.id) do |g|
      g.Say "Please press one to continue", voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
      g.Pause length: 5
      g.Say "Last chance. I didn't get any response. Please press one to continue.", 
        voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
      g.Pause length: 5
    end
  end
  render :xml => twiml_response.to_xml
end
```

This is what I've tried with voice control,

```
def voice
  twiml_response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    g.Say "Please say continue to continue", voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
    r.Record maxLength: 5, transcribeCallback: 
             transcriptions_path(question.id), 
             action: communications_menu_path(@question.id)  
    g.Say "Last chance. I didn't get any response. Please say continue to continue.", 
      voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
    r.Record maxLength: 5, transcribeCallback: 
             transcriptions_path(question.id), 
             action: communications_menu_path(@question.id)  
  end
  render :xml => twiml_response.to_xml
end
```

I have adapted my code from Twilio's survey controller. In that example the transcribed answers are stored, but that do not have any control over the question flow. In my case they do. How do I use `recordingStatusCallback` to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Using voice for responses like that is not as straightforward with Twilio right now because recording and transcription happen asynchronously to the call.

So, what you'd need to do is, once you hit the `action` URL for the [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) you won't have the recording or answer then. You could put the user into a loop (using [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) and [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect), for example) while you wait to receive the transcription and then use the [REST API to redirect the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#post) once you do get that response.

**[Edit]**

Here's what a redirect loop might look like:

```
def redirect_loop
  twiml_response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Pause length: "10"
    r.Redirect redirect_loop_path
  end
  render xml: twiml_response.to_xml
end
```

You could use whatever length pause you think is a good idea. It might be useful to have a short one so that you can measure how long this process takes. You could also use a pause of the maximum length you'd want a user to wait and then send them to a backup response or `<Gather>` based menu instead.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Won't that just redirect to itself forever?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with this one. I can't find a rails example that will show me how to do what I want. Can you tell me what I would have to add to the Twilio survey for rails that is on the net at `https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/automated-survey/ruby/rails#0`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right, that will loop forever. My point was that the `recordingStatusCallback` is fired outside of the main call flow, so it can't affect the call directly. What you need to do is put your caller into a state where they aren't moving on in the call until you get that webhook at which point you can get the Call SID and [use the API to redirect the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state#post) to the next action you want taken. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. That does make sense. I'll implement that and make sure I can get the recordingStatusCallback to fire. I don't understand your link "REST API to redirect the call". That's in PHP and I know nothing about PHP. It's only a few lines. How would that be done in rails?

Comment: On the docs you can switch the language the examples are written in, just check above the code and you should be able to switch to Ruby.

Comment: Thanks. It's there in ruby